# Cannot connect to Sql Server database: non-system databases are not shown

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, permissions, database-connection, system-databases

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 express database from Visual Studio 2010 using data connection wizard. I choose new connection -> MS Sql Server then I choose the only available server name (PAVEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS). The problem is i cannot see my database in the combobox below. System databases (like master, model, msdb etc) are shown though.
I've managed to find similar questions (like this one: [Cannot connect to SQL Server database in Visual Studio because my database isn't there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316282/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-database-in-visual-studio-because-my-database-isnt)) and it seems I'm having permission issues. However I cannot understand which user (and where) should I add.

The account name which I'm running my Visual Studio on is Pavel. My computer name is Pavel-PC. I'm not sure what my SQL Servers account names are, but it was installed using default settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question:

use "PAVEL-PC" instead of "PAVEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: I don't know what's wrong. I am trying with computer name. When I saw your post, try with computername\SQLEXPRESS. Then it work well.

Comment: @Megamind Well it probably was some weird configuration problem. Hostname\instanceName also worked well many times on other computers for me